# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

```
import React from 'react';

import CollectionsOverview from '../../components/collections-overview/collections-overview.component';

import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import CategoryPage from '../category/category.component';


const ShopPage = ({match}) =>{

    return (<div className="shop-page"> 

         <Routes>

           <Route exact path={ `${match.path}` } element={<CollectionsOverview />}/>

           <Route exact path={ `${match.path}/:categoryId`} element={<CategoryPage/>}/>
           
        </Routes>

    </div>

    )};

export default ShopPage;
```

Comment: rather than just posting code, can you describe the problem a little more

Comment: You seem to be using `react-router-dom` version 6. What is this `match` prop, where does it come from and what is its value? The error appears to be telling you that it's undefined. Can you share a more complete code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I think you're looking for `useMatch` :)

Answer (score 0):

The prop value `match` is undefined, which means that wherever you're using the `ShopPage` component, you have not defined the attribute, or the attribute value is undefined.

Thus, change it to something like:

```
<ShopPage match={somethinghere} />
```